# Error: bad line length character while executing a forced command script after git command

Tags: git, ssh, sh

I wrote a forced command script that must be executed for each git command over ssh. So, i add this line in my /.ssh/authorized_keys on server side:

```
command="/bin/wrapper.sh",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa....
```

And i put the wrapper.sh file in the bin folder with this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Execute the git command? (y/n)?"
read answer
if echo "$answer" | grep -iq "^y" ;then
    exec git-shell -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
else
    echo Goodbye
fi
```

So, when i launch any git command, for example git push origin master, on the client i get the follow error:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Exec
```

How i can fix it? I note that a not git command like:

```
ssh User@myhost ls
```

The script works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `git` over `ssh`, your local `git` will not allow you to interact with your script. It is using its protocol and the first `echo` will break the protocol (therefore the error).

It would be nice if it would work that way, but it does not.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected it. Do you know another way to customize the git commands on server side?